# Intellj python test: run individual Django tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, intellij-idea, django-testing

I have Django application inside IntelliJ IDE.
I can run all Django tests by calling the Django Tests runner.

But:
This is a time consuming and not ideal for development, where you would like to rerun one test that fail, and not run all 1000 others that are ok.

IntelliJ has options (UI) to run one test quickly, but this run python tests runner. 
I add `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=...` inside, but now I get other errors:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

I was looking to solve this error and I only found :

```
import django
django.setup()
```

inside Settings.py

My problem with this is:

- I think this breaks normal behaviour of the app. App works normal for different environments.
- It doesn't call code after this setup inside settings, so secret_key and others are not installed
- This doesn't seam to be really related to tests, but is changing the whole app.

So, I am looking for some settings, how to set the normal python tests, so that they will run as django tests.

### EDIT:

Now I change some thinks around and do:

1. Separate Settings for test
2. Do all the imports and then `django.setup()`

Now I get different error:

```
# The settings_test.py
SECRET_KEY = 'kdbaskdbkjadasd'

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'mobileapp',
]

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = '*'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = '...wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': '...',
        'USER': '...',
        'PASSWORD': '...',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

import django
django.setup()
```

error:

```
/Users/zadravecm/Work/.../env/bin/python3.6 /Users/zadravecm/Work/.../tests/tests.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zadravecm/Work/.../tests/tests.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ....Services import subsidiary_service as sub_service
  File "/Users/zadravecm/Work/.../Services/subsidiary_service.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ....models import *
  File "/Users/zadravecm/Work/.../models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "/Users/zadravecm/Work/.../env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/Users/zadravecm/Work/.../env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/Users/zadravecm/Work/.../env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 107, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/Users/zadravecm/Work/.../env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 252, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/Users/zadravecm/Work/.../env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 134, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Users/zadravecm/Work/.../env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/zadravecm/Work/.../env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 63, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Users/zadravecm/Work/.../env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/Users/zadravecm/Work/.../env/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Users/zadravecm/Work/.../settings_test.py", line 121, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/zadravecm/Work/.../env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/zadravecm/Work/.../env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 122, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/Users/zadravecm/Work/.../env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 24, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/Users/zadravecm/Work/.../env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/Users/zadravecm/Work/.../env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 47, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/Users/zadravecm/Work/.../env/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/Users/zadravecm/.../env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/admin.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import (
  File "/Users/zadravecm/Work/.../env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
ImportError: cannot import name 'User'
```

EDIT:

---

The image of the settings of a test runner that is run automatically, if I click run icon on tests.

[image]

Comment: IDEA should use Django test runner to excute a single test. I believe it's better to fix the initial problem instead of creating a hacky settings for tests. Could you please take a screenshot of the test run configuration created by the IDE when you execute a single test with a gutter icon?

Comment: I edit the question.

Comment: Thanks, it is not even a test run configuration, but a configuration for a pure Python script. How exactly did you create it? Did you click on a green triangle gutter icon in `tests.py`? Try to remove this run configuration before doing it, as IDE will reuse an existed config instead of creating a new one each time.